# How would you find a p threshold for a binary classification prediction?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, threshold, neyman-pearson-lemma, bayes-optimal-classifier

Lets say that there's a binary classification problem where $X$ ∈ $R_p$ and $Y ∈ \{0,1\} $ and $Pr(Y = 1 | X = x) = p$ for $p$ in $[0,1]$. There is a loss function $L_{falseneg} > 0$ for false prediction of Y = 0 when the outcome is Y = 1, and vice versa for $L_{falsepos}$. How would you find a threshold value so that expected  loss  criterion  for  making  a  prediction  is equivalent to predicting $Y= 1$ if $p ≥ threshold$ and predicting $Y = 0$ otherwise.

I thought about approaching it using Neymay Pearson Test, but would there be a simpler way to do this?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/109851/using-proper-scoring-rule-to-determine-class-membership-from-logistic-regression

Comment: You would maybe find [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/368979/111259) post enlightening.

Answer (score 0):

You could use your ground truth to set the threshold.
Create a ROC and/or a PRC, and select a threshold based on your use case.

What ratio of TP/FP is acceptable?
Is recall more important then precision, or the other way around - and by how much?

This changes by use case, and is mainly up to you.